# Adding additional functions to object literals after it has been created

Tags: javascript, function, methods, object-literal

So I was wondering whether this is the right way to add functions to an object created through object literals.

```js
var person = {
  firstname: "default",
  lastname: "default",
  greet: function () {
    return "hi " + this.firstname;
  }
}

var me = Object.create(person);

me.myFunction = function() {
  return console.log("meow");
};

console.log(me.myFunction());
```

However it returns an undefined after meow, is there any reason why it would do so?

Answer (score 1):

When you write

```
return console.log("meow");
```

you don't return "meow", but the return value of `console.log`, which is undefined. Modify the code like this:

```
me.myFunction = function() {
  return "meow";
};

console.log(me.myFunction());
```

Comment: thanks! completely overlook that part. is this the right way to add methods to an object literal after it has been created though?

Comment: Yes, it's perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

`console.log()` doesn't return any value, so the "fallback" value of the function is `undefined`.

Since you're returning the return value of `console.log` and log that again, you get `undefined`.

All of this has **nothing to do** with modifying an object or a prototype.

Answer (score 0):

You should return `meow` within `myFunction`:

```js
var person = {
  firstname: "default",
  lastname: "default",
  greet: function () {
    return "hi " + this.firstname;
  }
}

var me = Object.create(person);

me.myFunction = function() {
  return "meow";
};

document.write(me.myFunction());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var person = {
  firstname: "default",
  lastname: "default",
  greet: function () {
    return "hi " + this.firstname;
  }
}

var me = Object.create(person);

me.myFunction = function() {
  return console.log("meow");
};

console.log(me.myFunction());
```

why you return console.log() it's return nothing